# Finding median x-value of distribution function python

Tags: python, matplotlib, median

I have a dictionary that I want to plot. I'm trying to draw a vertical line at the x-value where 50% of all y-values lie above and 50% lie below.

I tried to do this by finding the median of the dict.values (y-values) and get the matching key. But I get a much too low x-value, that is defenately not the medium x-value. Does anyone have an idea how i can do this? Here is what i got so far:

```
hist1, hist2 = np.genfromtxt('./Unfold_Accessibility/social_shortest_path_durations_histogram.txt', unpack=True)

hist = np.genfromtxt('./Unfold_Accessibility/social_shortest_path_durations_histogram.txt')
dl1 = dict(hist)

median1 = dl1.keys()[dl1.values().index(np.median(dl1.values()))]

%matplotlib inline
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.plot(hist1, hist2, '-', color='blue', label='data')
ax.axvline(median1, color='blue', linestyle='--', label='mean p=1')
plt.title('Shortest Path Duration Cumulative') 
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.6, 1))
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Probability')
plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

[image: median_plot]
EDIT:okay so this is what i did now. not very pritty but it seems to be working:

```
yaverage1= np.sum(dl1.values())/2
untilhalf1 = 0
for key in dl1.iterkeys():
    if untilhalf1 < yaverage1:
        value = dl1[key]
        untilhalf1= untilhalf1 + value
    else:
        median1=[k for (k, v) in dl1.iteritems() if k == key]
        print 'median1:', median1
        break
```

Comment: Are you getting the same result in `median1` every time you run the program, or is the output changing?

Comment: no i alwas get the same result. I think the problem is that the median value off all y-value is pretty small (lets say y=5). So its taking the first value of the dictionary that is 5 and returs the matching key. which is then not the actual medium x-value

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort the keys before iterating through them:

For example:

```
def Quantile(self, distribution, quantile):
  target = np.sum(distribution.values()) * quantile
  currentsum = 0.0
  for key in sorted(distribution.keys()):
    if currentsum < target:
      currentsum = currentsum + distribution[key]
    if currentsum >= target:
      return key
```